# SourceAFIS Java - Create fingerprint template it's too slow

Tags: java, android, performance, fingerprint

I am using SourcesAFIS Fingerprint in an Android Java application to compare users' fingerprints and have the following problem: My application is taking too long to convert the user's fingerprint bytes into FingerprintTemplate, even sometimes the application is closed. To my misfortune I need to create this FingerprintTemplate object inside a loop in order to get the biometrics that are returned from the database, which ends up slowing down even more.

- Code snippet

  ```
      //Returns database biometries and assigns list
      listBiometria = conSql.selecionarBiometria();

      FingerprintTemplate candidate = new FingerprintTemplate();
      candidate.dpi(500);
      candidate.create(img);

      for(Biometry biometry : listBiometria)
      {
          FingerprintTemplate probe = new FingerprintTemplate()
                  .dpi(500)
                  .create(biometry.getBiometria());

          score = new FingerprintMatcher()
                  .index(probe)
                  .match(candidate);
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Well if in case anyone has a problem similar to this, I found the github of the creator of SourcesAFIS and asked this question there and received the following answer:Android feature extractor performance is indeed poor. Improvements are possible. Meantime it is recommended to use a recent device with solid floating-point performance.

In any case, you shouldn't be looping over images like that. Perform feature extraction after image acquisition and subsequently cache the template like the tutorial says.

Link: https://github.com/robertvazan/sourceafis-net/issues/2